# How do I use history.push in a react functional component?

Tags: reactjs

So im very new to programming with react and im struggling to redirect to a new page after hitting a button. Im working with react-hook-froms.

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import BoardService from '../service/BoardService';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(40),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

export default function BoardName() {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect");
    })

    
    const [id, getId] = useState(1);
    const history = useHistory();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        let board = {
            id: id,
            name: data.boardName
        }
            console.log(board);
            BoardService.createBoard(board.name, board);
            history.push(`createboard/created`);
    }

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Name des Boards
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate >
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        inputRef={register}
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="boardName"
                        label="Name"
                        name="boardName"
                        autoFocus
                    />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                    >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

the history.push isn't working in the onSubmit function and in the browser i keep getting the error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

I'm really stuck and not getting further. I'm happy for any help or advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your main index file with BrowserRouter using react-router-dom package

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

it should work.